# Increasing probability in consecutive events - how to calculate?

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a 15% chance of event ***E*** ocurring.
Every consecutive occurrence **increases the chances** by 15% per increment for 5 increments (15%/30%/45%/60%/75%).

What would be the chance of ***E*** occurring at every increment and how to calculate it ?

Edit (as suggested in comments): *P(E)* increases regardless of *E* occurring or not.

Thank you!

Edit2: It's a poorly stated and ill-conceived question. For anyone having a similar question, [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326034/probability-of-rolling-three-dice-without-getting-a-6) solves the same problem I stated (wrongly) above.

Comment: This is not at all clear.  I gather that, if $E$ occurs on the first trial, then the probability of $E$ on the second is now $.3$.  What if $E$ does not occur on the first trial?  Does it always reset to $.15$ after a fail?

Comment: I would suspect the answer may be $0.15 \times 0.3 \times 0.45 \times 0.6 \times 0.75 =5!\times 0.15^5$.  Strange things happen for seven increments

Comment: I agree to Henry.

Comment: Apologies if it's unclear! I'm having a hard time explaining it. No, it doesn't reset. It keeps raising.
A question would be, what is the cumulative probability of event E occurring after 2 trials (15% then 30%) in total ?
Should be higher than 30%, but how much higher ?

Comment: As others have remarked, if you only want to know the probability of getting $E$ five times in a row then you do have enough information and the answer is just the product (as @Henry ) has stated.  If you want something else then you have to explain what happens if $E$ does not occur.  If you want $P(E)$ to increase regardless of whether $E$ happens or not you should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Henry:  I agree and that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested in comments*

I would suspect the answer may be

$$0.15 \times 0.3 \times 0.45 \times 0.6 \times 0.75 =5!\times 0.15^5 = 0.0091125$$

Strange things happen for seven increments

Comment: As stated in my second edit, the question is not posed well. The linked question contains the "right" type of problem - calculating probability of getting at least one 6 in 5 die rolls, or in reverse, the probability of not getting a 6 in 5 rolls.
I solved my specific case like this:
(1-0.15)×(1-0.3)×(1-0.45)×(1-0.6)×(1-0.75) = 0.032725 or ~3.27% chance of the event not occurring after the last increment.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the problem in the following way:

-----------85----------///----------15----------- first occurrence

----85----//----15----///----70----//----30---- second occurrence

-85---15-//-70---30-///-70---30-//-55---45- third occurrence

and so on.