# Multiple six-sided dice rolls: Is there an alternative to the 1 − p(NOT) method for solving the probability of rolling "at least one" of a number?

Tags: probability, dice

Let's say we're talking about rolling a six. Here's what I know...

**For one roll ...**

(probability of rolling a six) = 1/6

(probability of NOT rolling a six) = 5/6

(probability of rolling a six) + (probability of NOT rolling a six) = 1/6 + 5/6 = 1

**For 'x' number of rolls ...**

(probability of rolling a six 'x' times) = (1/6)^x

(probability of NOT rolling a six 'x' times) = (5/6)^x

(probability of rolling at least one six in 'x' rolls)
= 1 − (probability of NOT rolling a six 'x' times)
= 1 − (5/6)^x

**My question:**

When trying to calculate the probability of rolling at least one six in 'x' rolls (the last line above), is there an alternative to this 1 − p(NOT six) method? Isn't the probability of rolling at least one six in 'x' rolls somehow a combination of the probabilities of rolling one six, two sixes, three sixes, four sixes etc.?

Comment: Sure.  You can just sum the probabilities of rolling exactly one, two,  etc.   It's  less efficient, but perfectly correct.

Comment: Nice to know, but what would that look like written out? Say, for at least one six in 5 rolls.

Comment: “Probability of NOT rolling a $6$ $x$ times” is ambiguous. It could  mean “(not rolling a six) $x$ times” or “not (rolling a six $x$ times.)”

Comment: Just sum the terms given by the binomial distribution.

Comment: One approach: At heart, the probability is $1-(1-1/6)^x.$ When you expand $(1-1/6)^x$ you get an alternating sum. That hints at an inclusion-exclusion argument. And, indeed, there is an inclusion-exclusion argument. Let $A_i$ be the cases where the $i$th roll is $6.$ Then you want $P(\lnot(A_1lor\cdots\lor A_x))$ and inclusion-exclusion gives the appropriate alternating sum.

Comment: "*what would that look like written out?*"  $\binom{5}{1}p(1-p)^4 + \binom{5}{2}p^2(1-p)^3+\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2+\binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p)+\binom{5}{5}p^5$ where $p=\frac{1}{6}$.  Recall your [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and consider $(x+y)^5$ where $x=\frac{1}{6}$ and $y=\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: If we take the simpler case of 3 rolls, then I can see 7 possible outcomes (where x = any number other than 6): 6xx, 66x, 666, x6x, xx6, x66, 6x6. Probability of exactly three sixes is (1/6)^2 = 1/216. Probability of exactly two sixes (either 66x, x66 or 6x6) is 3*(1/6)*(1/6)*(5/6) = 3*(5/216). Probability of exactly one six (either 6xx, x6x or xx6) is 3*(1/6)*(5/6)*(5/6) = 3*(25/216). Summing all of these gives 91/216, same as the solution to 1 − (5/6)^3. For a greater number of throws, I should probably learn a fancier method. Thanks anyway for the help everyone!

Comment: Closely related: [Probability of rolling three dice without getting a 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326034/probability-of-rolling-three-dice-without-getting-a-6)

Answer (score 1):

Probablity to get "at least" on six in $n$ rolls is obviously

$$P(X=1)+P(X=2)+\dots P(X=n)=1-P(X=0)$$

to calculate this probability you can use the binomial distribution that is

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k\cdot(1-p)^{n-k}$$

---

Let's have a simple example:

Let's roll 3 times a die (or one time 3 dice) and calcualate the probability to have "at least one six"

First approach (direct approach)

$$P(X\geq 1)=\binom{3}{1}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^1\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2+\binom{3}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^1+\binom{3}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0=\frac{91}{216}$$

Second (indirect) approach

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\binom{3}{0}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^0\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3=\frac{91}{216}$$